# Electoral populism

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjectives

I'm wondering whether *electoral populism* is tautological in a way; isn't *populism* inherently a vehicle to target a specific part of the *electorate*?

In which case would we, for instance, have non-electoral populism?

Even tough there is no confusion about the meaning of the term, I'm being a bit pedantic about the adjective *electoral* used; what purpose does it serve in this context?

In the context of reading the following passage on Turkey's president Erdogan allowing its Central Bank to raise the interest rate:

> The volatile mix of **electoral populism** and a rising dollar have pushed
>   the country to the brink of a currency crisis.

Comment: @SvenYargs The distinction being that the first would refer to the number of seats a candidate receives, as opposed to the number of votes. Could you elaborate on why this is relevant for the topic at hand?

Comment: Non-electoral populism would include mob-based rabble rousing such as Mussolini's [March on Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_on_Rome) or Hitler's use of violent mobs in [Kristallnacht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kristallnacht): electoral populism is populism that tries to gain power through electoral means. But this is off-topic and like most questions about alleged pleonasm probably trying to make a point (in this case a political one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat tautological/[pleonastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm), but not entirely.

The adjective *electoral* specifies further on what kind of *populism* it is about. Populism on its own is a political philosophy that aims to improve the rights of lower and middle class people as opposed to the elite.

It is hard to accurately tell what the writer means, but I think he means populism used as a strategy to gain the support of the people. So, it's a hypocritical way to gain political power for the elite instead of actually having a plan or organizational structure to improve the rights of the mass.

This kind of *electoral populism* becomes more apparent around the election times, in which the media are used, abused, and controlled to mobilize the people in favor of their party to gain political power.

> The volatile mix of electoral populism and a rising dollar have pushed the country to the brink of a currency crisis.

You might say *electoral populism* in this sentence means there is no economic plan that will help improve the position of the people.

Comment: Your last sentence is a plausible interpretation. My reading is that *electoral populism* as used by the media is code for cross-cultural right-wing extremism and crypto-fascism.

Comment: @DJohnson Could you elaborate on your interpretation? Associating right-wing extremism with *electoral populism* isn't mutually exclusive with boondoggle's reading.

Comment: Agreed. *EP* is a mushy term and anything but *MECE*. Here is a Brookings Institution article the first sentence of which reads, "The rise of populism, mostly right-leaning, is the most important European political development of the 21st century. "  https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2018/03/08/the-rise-of-european-populism-and-the-collapse-of-the-center-left/

Comment: +1 "electoral populism" is a euphemism for "rabble-rousing".